# With deprecation of the `SecurityContextRepository.loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder)` method, how do we add `Set-Cookie` to the response?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, migration, deprecation-warning

#### Context

We have for some time been using Spring-Security to protect our edge Spring-Boot Java applications.

Our system-wide authentication architecture (which is used by Spring-Boot apps, other Java apps and NodeJS apps) makes use of client-side session cookies (i.e. those that die when a browser window is closed) which store a session ID, and a cluster-internal session store keyed on those IDs.

### Implementation in Spring-Boot 2.6.x and below

For our Spring-Boot applications, we have a long-standing custom implementation of `SecurityContextRepository` where the implementation of the `SecurityContext loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder)` method performs something along the lines of the following:

1. If there is no session ID cookie, return an empty `SecurityContext`.
2. If there is a session ID cookie, which corresponds to a valid session, return a valid security context and, in some circumstances, add a `Set-Cookie` directive on the response to update the cookie.
3. If there is a session ID cookie, which does **not** correspond to a valid session, return an empty `SecurityContext`, and add a `Set-Cookie` directive on the response to clear the invalid cookie.

### Proposed implementation in Spring-Boot 2.7.x and above

Making the upgrade from Spring-Boot 2.6.x to 2.7.x, the `SecurityContext loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder)` method has been deprecated.  I've been looking at the alternative advised, namely `Supplier<SecurityContext> loadContext(HttpServletRequest)`, and wondering how to keep our system behaviour constant while migrating to the new APIs.  Referring to my numbering above, I have come to the conclusion so far that:

1. No change required - the response was never used
2. If we need to update the cookie on the response, then ensure that the relevant information is available in the `SecurityContext` that we return, and then customise the `saveContext()` implementation to ensure the cookie is updated if necessary
3. Return an empty `SecurityContext` as before, and customise the `saveContext()` implementation to ensure the cookie is cleared in if the security context is empty.

#### The question(s)

I'd be grateful if one of the Spring team, or another enlightened StackOverflow user, would be able to confirm that the above migration strategy is appropriate, or correct me if I have misunderstood anything.

If I have got it right, perhaps it would be worth updating the Javadoc of the deprecated method to make it clearer for other users also?

Many thanks.

Comment: I came across this posting while investigating a breaking change between Spring Security `6.0.0-M3` and `6.0.0-M4`. Turns out that the default for `requireExplicitSave` on the `SecurityContextConfigurer` [changed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11110) - from `false` to `true` causing the cookie not to be created upon login (for one of my tests). Long story short, the documentation in regards to `SecurityContextRepository` is rather slim - this seems to be the only doc there is: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/persistence.html

Comment: @GunnarHillert yes, the documentation is lacking. I don't know how to get current "SecurityContextRepository" instance from authentication filter and handlers, because the doc only says to use it, but doesn't say how to get it. It's not a bean and constructing your own in the filters seems totally wrong (and requires other arguments which I don't have).

Comment: Encountered the same problem. A solution that works for me is to create the SpringContextRepository bean manually


  @Bean
  public DelegatingSecurityContextRepository delegatingSecurityContextRepository() {
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
        new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
        new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
  }


and then configure it

`http.securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext.securityContextRepository(delegatingSecurityContextRepository()))`

Comment: Hey Olaf, have you implemented a working solution, and would you mind sharing it?

Comment: @Daniel Sadly not. We are still using the old implementation with `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` in place.
I came to look at this ticket again just now when I chanced upon the `TODO` in our code that is waiting for a response from the Spring team :-(

Comment: @Daniel update - see my own answer below for details of what we did.  It's now working for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

18 months on from asking this question, I went on to tackle this, as when you upgrade to Spring-Boot 3 it's no longer optional - although the `loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder)` method is still there and deprecated, when it's invoked by Spring, the inner `HttpServletResponse` object is always `null`.

The answer to my question is fundamentally that my proposed implementation was a good one.

Some more details of how we moved forward, in case it is useful to readers of this question:

1. Our implementation of `SecurityContext` now includes a  `List<AuthorizationResultAction> actions` field, in addition to the nullable `Authentication` field.
2. The `AuthorizationResultAction` class is really just a way of defining a deferred operation to be performed on the `HttpServletResponse` object, once that's available.
3. In our implementation of `SecurityContextRepository.loadContext()` / `loadDeferredContext()` etc, we populate the `actions` with whatever we want to be done, and ensure that we always return an instance of our `SecurityContext` class (including where we previously might have called `SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext()`)
4. In our implementation of `SecurityContextRepository.saveContext()`, where previously we did nothing, we now:

   - if the provided `SecurityContext` is an instance of our implementation, then check for any `actions`, and apply them
   - otherwise, if the `SecurityContext` has `getAuthentication() == null` - which might be, for example, from a rejected `containsContext()` operation - then do what we want to in this context (which in our case, is to clear the session ID cookie).